# Why are my gem 'dotenv-rails' variables not loading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables

- gem 'dotenv-rails' is required in gemfile test and development environments.
- .env file is saved in root
- I believe variables use correct syntax; USERNAME=username
- I am using Rails 5.0.4
- I have not required 'dotenv-rails' anywhere, as the [docs](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) do not suggest that I need to.

When playing in the console, the only way I can access the variables is by calling, Dotenv.load in each session. Suggesting that `Dotenv.load` should be called somewhere in config of my app.

Comment: try calling `Dotenv::Railtie.load` on your `config/application.rb`

Comment: Thanks @akz92 that did it, didn't seem clear from the docs that that code block was required unless you wanted 'sooner than normal' initialization! Does one need `HOSTNAME = ENV['HOSTNAME']` to be declared in `config/application.rb` also? Please submit as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks again.

Comment: No, the `HOSTNAME` is just part of the example. Unfortunately I don't know why this happens, that's just how I solved this issue on my projects.

Comment: Aha, of course, ijiot I am!.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `Dotenv::Railtie.load` to your `config/application.rb`

Comment: when I add Dotenv::Railtie.load, it gives me this error "/home/ubuntu/workspace/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Dotenv::Railtie (NameError)
Did you mean?  Rails"

Comment: @KickButtowski no, that's the right name. Maybe the gem isn't being loaded at all. Check the docs: https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#note-on-load-order

Comment: god bless your comment about that gem is not being loaded which helped me alot

Answer (score 3):

You may also need to restart Spring.

`bin/spring stop`

It will restart once you run another `rails` command.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone else:

This happened to me once. As it turns out, I was mistakenly passing `RAILS_ENV=production` in the environment variables, disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

For me the `bin/spring stop` fixed the issue and I am using ruby 3.1.2 and rails 7.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

I had success with

```
require_relative "boot"

require "dotenv" 
Dotenv.load      

require "rails/all"
```